# How can I sort an array so that the output is always an array, even when the input array is empty?

Tags: powershell

I have a variable `$try` that contains an array, and I want `$res` to contain the sorted version of `$try`. This seems easy enough, but I can't get this to work when `$try` happens to contain an *empty* array.

When `$try` contains a non-empty array, no problem:

```
PS C:\data> $try = @("a", "c", "b")

PS C:\data> $res = $try | Sort-Object

PS C:\data> $res
a
b
c

PS C:\data> $res.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

However, when the input array is empty, the output object is `$null`, *not* (as I would have expected) an empty array:

```
PS C:\data> $try = @()

PS C:\data> $res = $try | Sort-Object

PS C:\data> $res

PS C:\data> $null -eq $res
True

PS C:\data> $null -eq $try
False
```

I want `$res` to be the sorted version of `$try`, even if `$try` happens to contain an empty array. In that case, I want `$res` to *also* be an empty array.

Is there a way of doing this other than something like:

```
PS C:\data> $try = @()

PS C:\data> if ($try) {$res = $try | Sort-Object} else { $res = @() }

PS C:\data> $null -eq $try
False

PS C:\data> $null -eq $res
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force `$res` to be an array like this, even when `$try` is $null or an empty array:

```
$try = $null  # or an empty array @()
$res = @($try | Sort-Object)

# $res is now an array with 0 elements
$res.GetType()
```

Result

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----      --------                                                                                   
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
```

Comment: I think I'm still missing some basic PowerShell knowledge, because my initial reading of @($try | Sort-Object) leads me to think that this would result in an array that has a single member, namely the sorted array. But since your suggestion works, the result of $try | Sort-Object must not be an array itself, so I have some PowerShell learning to do it seems. :) (But it does surprise me a bit that a gazillion "How to sort an array in PowerShell" blog posts don't mention this, and just pipe the unsorted array to Sort-Object).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise your res variable and append to res your result sort :

```
$try = @()
$res=@()
$res += $try | Sort-Object
```